# Using python to extract a few lines from a data file

Tags: python

I have a large file which has an enormous of data in it. I need to extract 3 lines every 5000 or so lines. The format of the data file is as follows:

...

```
O_sh          9215    1.000000   -2.304400   
 -1.0680E+00  1.3617E+00 -5.7138E+00  
O_sh          9216    1.000000   -2.304400  
 -8.1186E-01 -1.7454E+00 -5.8169E+00  
timestep    501      9216         0         3    0.000500  
   20.54      -11.85       35.64      
  0.6224E-02   23.71       35.64      
  -20.54      -11.86       35.64      
Li               1    6.941000    0.843200
  3.7609E-02  1.1179E-01  4.1032E+00
Li               2    6.941000    0.843200
  6.6451E-02 -1.3648E-01  1.0918E+01
```

...

What I need is the the three lines after the line that starts with "timestep" so in this case I need the 3x3 array:

```
   20.54      -11.85       35.64      
  0.6224E-02   23.71       35.64      
  -20.54      -11.86       35.64
```

in an output file for each time the word "timestep" appears.

Then I need the average of all those arrays in just one array. Just one array consisting of the average value of each element in the same position in every array for the whole file.
I've been working on this for a while, but I haven't been able to extract the data correctly yet.

Thanks so much, and this is not for homework. You're advice will be helping the progress of science! =)

Thanks,

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  Is regex a requirement, or just the first approach you've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using a [coroutine](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/) (which is basically a generator that can accept values, if you are unfamiliar) to keep a running average as you iterate over your file.

```
def running_avg():
    count, sum = 0, 0
    value = yield None
    while True:
        if value:
            sum += value
            count += 1
        value = yield(sum/count)

# array for keeping running average
array = [[running_avg() for y in range(3)] for x in range(3)]

# advance to first yield before we begin
[[elem.next() for elem in row] for row in array]

with open('data.txt') as f:
    idx = None
    for line in f:
        if idx is not None and idx < 3:
            for i, elem in enumerate(line.strip().split()):
                array[idx][i].send(float(elem))
            idx += 1
        if line.startswith('timestep'):
            idx = 0
```

To get a convert `array` into a list of averages, just call each coroutine `next` method, it'll return current average:

```
averages = [[elem.next() for elem in row] for row in array]
```

And you'd get something like:

```
averages = [[20.54, -11.85, 35.64], [0.006224, 23.71, 35.64], [-20.54, -11.86, 35.64]]
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what happened here, but you're converting the 3x3 arrays into 9x1 lists then taking the average of the entire list, which is not exactly what I need. Instead I need each of those lists added up and then each element of that list divided by the number of samples.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood then, I was going off what you said in a comment on another answer. I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Maimon I'm averaging each line in the file that is part of the "array". Thus using your example data you'd get 3 lines of averages written out. Is that what you were trying to do?

Comment: @zeekay I'm sorry, I'm having a bit of trouble making myself clear. What I have here is a file with 1000 (or so) 3x3 arrays. Each array comes after the 'timestep' line. What I want is a single 3x3 array that consists of the average value for each element in those 1000 arrays. Looking like this: [[avg(a),avg(b),avg(c)],[avg(d),avg(e),avg(f],[avg(g),avg(h),avg(i)]]

Comment: Ah, ok, updated back to the old code, averaging as you iterate through the lines in the file, appending each row in the array to a defaultdict keyed to the index of the array.

Comment: OK, I'm not sure how to explain this in a different way. When I print arrays.values() I get an enormous list, much larger than a simple 3x3 array. All I want is a single 3x3 array of the format I posted:  [[avg(a),avg(b),avg(c)],[avg(d),avg(e),avg(f],[avg(g),avg(h),avg(i)]] simply adding up each a, each b, each c, etc... and coming up with 9 numbers. Each of those nine numbers should then be divided by the number of samples.  Thank you so much for your help and your patience.

Comment: Yeah I don't have any idea what you are talking about. For your entire file you want to return a 3x3 array? How are the averages of a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i calculated? The average of each element in that position across every array?

Comment: Yes exactly, just one array consisting of the average of each element in its position in each individual array.

Comment: You mean the average of each position across all arrays right?

Comment: I mean if [[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3]] and [[3,3,3], [2,2,2], [1,1,1]] were all the arrays I had, it would sum to [[4,4,4], [4,4,4], [4,4,4]] and average out to [[2,2,2], [2,2,2], [2,2,2]]. So, yeah I guess.

Comment: @zeekay Thank you so much for your help. I've been struggling on this problem without adequate training in programming, and your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Haha, no problem! I really struggled just to understand what you wanted. Maybe next time in big bold letters do like: *SAMPLE OUTPUT* in your question and I'll catch it. Re-reading the question now it should have been pretty obvious what you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is not homework, I think regex is overkill for the problem.  If you know that you need three lines after one starts with 'timestep' why not approach the problem this way:

```
Matrices = []

with open('data.txt') as fh:
  for line in fh:
    # If we see timestep put the next three lines in our Matrices list.
    if line.startswith('timestep'):
      Matrices.append([next(fh) for _ in range(3)])
```

Per the comments - you use next(fh) in this situation to keep the file handle in sync when you want to pull the next three lines from it.  Thanks!

Comment: The idea is right, but using `while True/readline/break` is the wrong way. Just use `for line in fh:`.

Comment: Won't using `for line in fh:` have trouble when you attempt to read 3 lines within the loop?  Or does the for loop not care that the file handle position has advanced since it's previous iteration?

Comment: - Call `next(fh)` instead of `fh.readline()` to keep things in synch.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you can do this:

Algorithm:

```
Read the file line by line
if the line starts with "timestep":
    read the next three lines
    take the average as needed
```

Code:

```
def getArrays(f):
    answer = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
    count = 0
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        if line.strip().startswith("timestep"):
            one, two, three = getFloats(f.readline().strip()), getFloats(f.readline().strip()), getFloats(f.readline().strip())
            answer[0][0] = ((answer[0][0]*count) + one[0])/(count+1)
            answer[0][1] = ((answer[0][0]*count) + one[1])/(count+1)
            answer[0][2] = ((answer[0][0]*count) + one[2])/(count+1)

            answer[1][0] = ((answer[0][0]*count) + two[0])/(count+1)
            answer[1][1] = ((answer[0][0]*count) + two[1])/(count+1)
            answer[1][2] = ((answer[0][0]*count) + two[2])/(count+1)

            answer[2][0] = ((answer[0][0]*count) + three[0])/(count+1)
            answer[2][1] = ((answer[0][0]*count) + three[1])/(count+1)
            answer[2][2] = ((answer[0][0]*count) + three[2])/(count+1)
        line = f.readline()
        count += 1
    return answer

def getFloats(line):
    answer = []
    for num in line.split():
        if "E" in num:
            parts = num.split("E")
            base = float(parts[0])
            exp = int(parts[1])
            answer.append(base**exp)
        else:
            answer.append(float(num))
    return answer
```

`answer` is now a list of all the 3x3 arrays. I don't know how you want to do the averaging, so if you post that, I can incorporate it into this algorithm. Else, you can write a function to take my array and compute the averages are required.

Hope this helps

Comment: I just need a straight elementwise averaging, preferably printed to a separate file.

Comment: Using this code, does anyone know how to get the average 3x3 array of this collection of all the arrays?

Comment: @Maimon: so if you have a 3x3 array that looks like this: [[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]], what would the result of the result of the averaging look like?

Comment: the result of the averaging would be a 3x3 array, what I have here is a collection of 3x3 arrays, each being of the format [[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]], what I need is each of those elements added up separately so that I have an array. I can then divide each element of that summed array by the number of samples.

Comment: So if you had an array that looks like this: [[a1,b1,c1],[d1,e1,f1],[g1,h1,i1], [a2,b2,c2],[d2,e2,f2],[g2,h2,i2], [a3,b3,c3],[d3,e3,f3],[g3,h3,i3]], then would this be the result: [[avg(a1, b1, c1), avg(d1, e1, f1), avg(g1, h1, i1)], [avg(a2, b2, c2), avg(d2, e2, f2), avg(g2, h2, i2)], [avg(a3, b3, c3), avg(d3, e3, f3), avg(g3, h3, i3)]]?

Comment: Not quite. If I had that set up, I would want each 'a' each 'b' each 'c' etc... added up and averaged to make an array of format: [[avg(a),avg(b),avg(c)],[avg(d),avg(e),avg(f],[avg(g),avg(h),avg(i)]]

Comment: I've added the functionality that you've asked for. I haven't had time to test it, so if it doesn't work, comment and I will edit it

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "cell_vector_extract1.py", line 33, in <module>
        getArrays(history)
      File "cell_vector_extract1.py", line 7, in getArrays
        one, two, three = getFloats(f.readline()),     getFloats(f.readline()), getFloats(f.readline())
      File "cell_vector_extract1.py", line 28, in getFloats
        exp = int(parts[1])
    IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cell_vector_extract1.py", line 36, in <module>
    getArrays(history)
  File "cell_vector_extract1.py", line 8, in getArrays
    answer[0][0] = ((answer[0][0]*count) + one[0])/(count+1)
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Try it now (still untested). Let me know if it still doesn't work, and I will test it after work hours

Answer (score 0):

Building on inspectorG4dget's and g.d.d.c's posts, here's a version that should do the reading, parsing, and averaging.  Please point out my bugs! :)

```
    def averageArrays(filename):
        # initialize average variables then,
        # open the file and iterate through the lines until ...
        answer, count = [[0.0]*3 for _ in range(3)], 0
        with open(filename) as fh:
            for line in fh:
                if line.startswith('timestep'):  # ... we find 'timestep'!
                    # so , we read the three lines and sanitize them
                    # conversion to float happens here, which may be slow
                    raw_mat = [fh.next().strip().split() for _ in range(3)]
                    mat = []
                    for row in raw_mat:
                        mat.append([float(item) for item in row])
                    # now, update the running average, noting overflows as by
                    # http://invisibleblocks.wordpress.com/2008/07/30/long-running-averages-without-the-sum-of-preceding-values/
                    # there are surely more pythonic ways to do this
                    count += 1
                    for r in range(3):
                        for c in range(3):
                            answer[r][c] += (mat[r][c] - answer[r][c]) / count
        return answer
```

Comment: I get this error when your code is run:  File "cell_vector_extract1.py", line 23, in <module>
    averageArrays(history)
  File "cell_vector_extract1.py", line 5, in averageArrays
    with open(filename) as fh:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found

Comment: `filename` should be a string of the filename.  So, `'history.dat'` might be it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
from itertools import imap

text = '''O_sh          9215    1.000000   -2.304400
 -1.0680E+00  1.3617E+00 -5.7138E+00
O_sh          9216    1.000000   -2.304400
 -8.1186E-01 -1.7454E+00 -5.8169E+00
timestep    501      9216         0         3    0.000500
   20.54      -11.85       35.64
  0.6224E-02   23.71       35.64
  -20.54      -11.86       35.64
Li               1    6.941000    0.843200
  3.7609E-02  1.1179E-01  4.1032E+00
Li               2    6.941000    0.843200
  6.6451E-02 -1.3648E-01  1.0918E+01
O_sh          9215    1.000000   -2.304400
 -1.0680E+00  1.3617E+00 -5.7138E+00
O_sh          9216    1.000000   -2.304400
 -8.1186E-01 -1.7454E+00 -5.8169E+00
timestep    501      9216         0         3    0.000500
   80.80      -14580       42.28
  7.5224E-01   777.1       42.28
  140.54      -33.86       42.28
Li               1    6.941000    0.843200
  3.7609E-02  1.1179E-01  4.1032E+00
Li               2    6.941000    0.843200
  6.6451E-02 -1.3648E-01  1.0918E+01'''

lin = '\r?\n{0}*({1}+){0}+({1}+){0}+({1}+){0}*'
pat = ('^timestep.+'+3*lin).format('[ \t]','[.\deE+-]')
regx = re.compile(pat,re.MULTILINE)

def moy(x):
    return sum(map(float,x))/len(x)

li = map(moy,zip(*regx.findall(text)))
n = len(li)
g = iter(li).next
res = [(g(),g(),g()) for i in xrange(n//3)]
print res
```

result

```
[(50.67, -7295.925, 38.96), (0.379232, 400.40500000000003, 38.96), (60.0, -22.86, 38.96)]
```